# How to use return from an asynchronous directly in a condition

Tags: javascript, function, callback, ecmascript-6, return-value

With the help of stackoverflow I figured out how to return a value from an asynchronous function.

But now I'm struggling how to use the return directly in a condition.

Here you can have a look at my code:

```
function playerExists(n, fn) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM dorftrophy.spieler;', function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
            const player = results.map(entry => entry.nr); 
            console.log(n);
            console.log(player);
            console.log(player.includes(Number.parseInt(n)));
            fn(player.includes(Number.parseInt(n)));
        });
    }
    const form = {
        playerNr: {
            q: 'Please enter Player number:',
            error: 'Wrong input...',
            validator: (message, callback) => {
                if(message.text && isNumeric(message.text) && playerExists(message.text, function(exists){return exists})) {
                    callback(true, message.text)
                    return
                }

                callback(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

Look at the if clause. There is this condition:

```
playerExists(message.text, function(exists){return exists})
```

I'm searching for a solution where the return of the function playerExists (returns true or false), has directly an effect to the condition.

I guess something I'm doing wrong... Unfortunately I was not able to find a solution on myself.

Comment: I don't think you *did* figure out how to return a value from an asynchronous function, because you *can't*.

Comment: playerExists(message.text, function(exists){return exists})) but the exists has true or false in it? So I though it should be possible to use inside the condition? Or am I wrong...?

Comment: You're wrong :)  You **cannot** return a useful value from an asynchronous operation like what you've got. Instead, you have to do the work you want to do **inside** that callback function you pass.

Comment: The only way to achieve that would be using promises and `await`.